# Select one row of two rows have the same grade from per_grades

Tags: oracle

I have two rows with the same value in grade name in table per_grades , i want to select one of them .
I tried max but i get nothing .
may any one help me ?

Comment: Some more details?

Comment: In per_grades table column (name) represents the grade of the employee , this column is not primary key , my problem is i have a query that retrieves managers of employee ,there is two managers with the same grade , i need to select only one of them , is that clear ?

Comment: For future, you can edit your question to add any more information instead of commenting your own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` analytical function. This will return only one manager for employee with same grade and you can use this query on multiple employees in where clause.

```
SELECT NAME, GRADE, ... FROM
(SELECT NAME, GRADE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YOUR_EMPLOYEE ORDER BY GRADE) AS RN
...
FROM 
...
WHERE
...)
Where rn=1
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Could show your query. Like this:

```
 with tbl as 
(SELECT 1 as id,  'same' as name from DUAL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,  'same' from DUAL)
SELECT max(id) FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.name = 'same'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select any row with same name then you can use:

```
select id, name from per_grades where name='same' and rownum<2;
```